# Can I attend two back-to-back conferences in two EU countries on one Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, europe, schengen-visas

I am attending two conferences, back to back, in two different EU countries. I have time to apply to only one visa. Is it possible to travel from one Schengen country to another for this purpose with no problems?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's the purpose of the Schengen Zone; to encourage inter-European trade and commerce.

You need to apply in the EU country that you will be spending the most time in and if it's a tie in terms of days, you need to apply to the first country you will be landing in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your Schengen visa is valid throughout the whole schengen area.  You can see the official statement

> A Schengen visa is a short stay visa allowing its holder to circulate
>   in the Schengen area.  The Schengen area covers 26 countries
>   ("Schengen States") without border controls between them. These
>   countries are: Austria, Belgium, the Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia,
>   Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia,
>   Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, the Netherlands, Norway,
>   Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden and Switzerland.
>
> A Schengen visa is an authorisation issued by a Schengen State with a
>   view to:
>
> transit through or an intended stay in the territory of the Schengen
>   States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180 days period
>   ("short stay visa"), transit through the international transit areas
>   of airports of the Schengen States ("airport transit visa").

in the official EU commission website, [here](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/schengen_visa_en).

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps it should also be noted that the OP should describe and document his entire trip in the single visa application he makes -- that is, not just the part that it in the country he applies to.

Comment: Agree 100%.  I assume, for the purpose of the question, that the OP plans to request a visa on the basis of his planned trip, and he will describe the intent, extent and details of his travel plans to the authorities.

Comment: You can also go to **some** EU countries that are not part of Schengen yet with a Schengen visa: Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Romania

Comment: @BritishSam: Beware that some of those countries have additional conditions about the Schengen visa being multiple-entry or still having unused entries left.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point